# Как в AngularJS передать переменную

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

В контроллерах есть такая функция, задающая параметры графика:

```
function sparklineChartCtrl() {
  var longLineData = [34, 43, 43, 35];
  var longLineOptions = {
    type: 'line',
    lineColor: '#17997f',
    fillColor: '#ffffff'
  };
  this.longLineData = longLineData;
  this.longLineOptions = longLineOptions;
}
```

Сам график выводится вот так:

```
<div ng-controller="sparklineChartCtrl as spark">
    <div sparkline spark-data="spark.inlineData" spark-options="spark.inlineOptions"></div>
</div>
```

График строится и все работает, когда массив `longLineData` прописан руками в контроллере (как тут в примере). Но при попытке взять массив через запрос `$http.get()`, ничего не работает.

Задача с помощью `$http.get('url')` передать значение массива в переменную `this.longLineData`. Я совсем новичок, пробовал по-разному, не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается это с помощью конструкции вида

```
var self = this;
//Выполняем запрос на сервер
//при успешном выполнении которого в переменную `longLineData`
//будет записан результат
$http.get('url').then(function(result) {
    self.longLineData = result.data;
    console.log('self.longLineData:', self.longLineData);
});
```

Comment: немного отформатировал Ваш вопрос, дописал комментарий.

Comment: `var self = this;
    $http.get('url').then(function(result) {
        self.longLineData = result.data;
    });
    console.log(this.longLineData);`


@Bald, @a-bobkov, в консоль _this.longLineData_ выводится как _undefined_. Что не так?

Comment: @Dmitry *предполагаю* что результат запроса на сервер был не успешен, попробуй изменить так: `return $http.get('url').then(function(result){ console.log('success'); console.log(result.data);}, function(response){console.log(response);});` и посмотри в консоли что выводится

Comment: @Bald, html запрос отрабатывает нормально. С вашим кодом выдается в логи такой ответы: `success` и `Object data:Array[30]`. Т.е. внутри `$http.get()` все хорошо. Но при попытке вынести данные на уровень выше, за пределы функции, они превращаются в _undefined_.

Comment: @Dmitry console.log надо занести в функцию и поставить после присвоения. Я добавил в ответ.

Comment: @a-bobkov, внутри функции поставил `self.longLineData = result.data;
            console.log(self.longLineData);`, ответ в консоль `Object {data: Array[30]}`. Как теперь это передать за пределы `$http.get()` и передать в переменную `this.longLineData`?

Comment: @Dmitry А оно уже там, ничего больше делать не надо. Просто если вы ставите печать после функции, то печать выполняется до выполнения http запроса и показывает undefined. Вы лучше отладчиком посмотрите, например DevTools.

Comment: @a-bobkov, а как проверить, что переменная дошла сюда `<div sparkline spark-data="chart.longLineData" spark-options="chart.longLineOptions"></div>`? График так и не рисуется.

Comment: @Dmitry Например, можно вывести переменную в html с помощью {{longLineData}} (только нужно в строку ее превратить, конечно). Скорее всего, график нужно перерисовывать явной командой - какой-нибудь update() запускать. Вряд ли он сам следит за тем, что вы ему подменили данные.

Comment: @a-bobkov, правильно я понимаю, что функция контроллера быстрее отрабатывает, чем функция $http.get() получает значение по http запросу? И данные в приложение поступают с задержкой из-за чего функция построения графика отрабатывает без данных? и для того чтобы график построился, надо найти функцию которая его строит и по аналогу ее сделать функцию обновления? все правильно?

Comment: @Dmitry Да, скорее всего именно так.

Comment: спасибо. Пойду копать дальше. :-)

Comment: @Dmitry Пож-ста. На этом сайте принято, чтобы автор отмечал понравившийся ответ либо как "правильный", либо как "полезный" :)

Comment: @Dmitry "и для того чтобы график построился, надо найти функцию которая его строит и по аналогу ее сделать функцию обновления" - не обязательно, достаточно написать `<div sparkline ng-if="spark.longLineData" ...`

Comment: @norbornen, все заработало! Спасибо всем! :-)